# Simplifying the output for the comparision of 2d list

Tags: python

I have copied over about 2000 lines of `tuples` to a `list` from a `txt` file. Now i need to each element in the `list` to the subsequent elements in the rest of the `list` and i need compare each element only once **i.e** if i take the first element and compared with every element in the list then i can discard it for the rest of the comparison.

This is my code for comparison block:

```
R = [(20, 12, 40, 42, 45), (40, 21, 40, 42, 49),
    (6, 19, 22, 36, 48), (2, 5, 20, 24, 33),
    (8, 12, 24, 28, 44), (3, 15, 29, 30, 37),
    (20, 17, 30, 33, 43), (3, 15, 16, 29, 42),
    (17, 18, 20, 35, 39), (20, 21, 23, 43, 48),
    (14, 24, 30, 40, 45)...]


for lineno1, tup in enumerate(R):
    print("")
    # iterate over the current tuple
    for i, num in enumerate(tup):
        # compare every number in the tuple to the rest of the list
        for lineno2 in range(lineno1+1, len(R)):
            tup2 = R[lineno2]
            if num == tup2[i]:
                print(f"In line: {lineno1+1} {tup} No. '{num} is found in line {lineno2+1} {tup2}.")
                break
```

My Output:

```
line: 1 (20, 12, 40, 42, 45) No. 20 is found in line '7' (20, 17, 30, 33, 43).
    line: 1 (20, 12, 40, 42, 45) No. 12 is found in line '5' (8, 12, 24, 28, 44).
    line: 1 (20, 12, 40, 42, 45) No. 40 is found in line '2' (40, 21, 40, 42, 49).
    line: 1 (20, 12, 40, 42, 45) No. 42 is found in line '2' (40, 21, 40, 42, 49).
    line: 1 (20, 12, 40, 42, 45) No. 45 is found in line '11' (14, 24, 30, 40, 45).
    
    line: 2 (40, 21, 40, 42, 49) No. 21 is found in line '10' (20, 21, 23, 43, 48).
    
    line: 3 (6, 19, 22, 36, 48) No. 48 is found in line '10' (20, 21, 23, 43, 48).
    
    line: 4 (2, 5, 20, 24, 33) No. 20 is found in line '9' (17, 18, 20, 35, 39).
    
    
    line: 6 (3, 15, 29, 30, 37) No. 3 is found in line '8' (3, 15, 16, 29, 42).
    line: 6 (3, 15, 29, 30, 37) No. 15 is found in line '8' (3, 15, 16, 29, 42).
    
    line: 7 (20, 17, 30, 33, 43) No. 20 is found in line '10' (20, 21, 23, 43, 48).
    line: 7 (20, 17, 30, 33, 43) No. 30 is found in line '11' (14, 24, 30, 40, 45).
```

I need help formatting the output, in my output i get five lines of output for a single `tuple` i need to simplify it and get a clean output. I want to get output of each `tuple` in a single line, because i have more than 1500 `tuples` and it would take about 7500 lines .

I want output that looks something like this

```
Line 1: (20, 12, 40, 42, 45) (7, 5, 2, 2, 11)  #Right side values are  line numbers of the respective element in the tuple
Line 2: (40, 21, 40, 42, 49) (0, 10, 0, 0, 0)
Line 3: (6, 19, 22, 36, 48) (0, 0, 0, 0, 10)
Line 4: (2, 5, 20, 24, 33) (0, 0, 9, 0, 0)
Line 6: (3, 15, 29, 30, 37) (8, 8, 0, 0, 0)
Line 7: (20, 17, 30, 33, 43) (10, 0, 11, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a lot of loops :) Note that some rows have multiple matches to another row. I left them in.

```
R = [(20, 12, 40, 42, 45), 
     (40, 21, 40, 42, 49),
     (6, 19, 22, 36, 48), 
     (2, 5, 20, 24, 33),
     (8, 12, 24, 28, 44), 
     (3, 15, 29, 30, 37),
     (20, 17, 30, 33, 43), 
     (3, 15, 16, 29, 42),
     (17, 18, 20, 35, 39), 
     (20, 21, 23, 43, 48),
     (14, 24, 30, 40, 45)]
     
     
for i,x in enumerate(R):
   for ie, e in enumerate(x):
       for rw in range(i+1, len(R)):
          if e == R[rw][ie]:
             print(f"In line: {i+1} {x} No. '{e}' is found in line {rw+1} {R[rw]}")
             break
```

Output

```
In line: 0 (20, 12, 40, 42, 45) No. '20' is found in line 6 (20, 17, 30, 33, 43)
In line: 0 (20, 12, 40, 42, 45) No. '12' is found in line 4 (8, 12, 24, 28, 44)
In line: 0 (20, 12, 40, 42, 45) No. '40' is found in line 1 (40, 21, 40, 42, 49)
In line: 0 (20, 12, 40, 42, 45) No. '42' is found in line 1 (40, 21, 40, 42, 49)
In line: 0 (20, 12, 40, 42, 45) No. '45' is found in line 10 (14, 24, 30, 40, 45)
In line: 1 (40, 21, 40, 42, 49) No. '21' is found in line 9 (20, 21, 23, 43, 48)
In line: 2 (6, 19, 22, 36, 48)  No. '48' is found in line 9 (20, 21, 23, 43, 48)
In line: 3 (2, 5, 20, 24, 33)   No. '20' is found in line 8 (17, 18, 20, 35, 39)
In line: 5 (3, 15, 29, 30, 37)  No. '3'  is found in line 7 (3, 15, 16, 29, 42)
In line: 5 (3, 15, 29, 30, 37)  No. '15' is found in line 7 (3, 15, 16, 29, 42)
In line: 6 (20, 17, 30, 33, 43) No. '20' is found in line 9 (20, 21, 23, 43, 48)
In line: 6 (20, 17, 30, 33, 43) No. '30' is found in line 10 (14, 24, 30, 40, 45)
```

Comment: Yours and @wups gives me the exact output i need, thanks. If you know efficient and pythonic way  to solve this problem, like using inbuilt functions, that'll be very helpful in `refactorting` the code

Answer (score 1):

Three nested loops don't seem to be very efficient, but it's the most obvious solution to me.
For every tuple in the list, iterate over every number in the tuple and compare it to the number at the same position in every tuple in the rest of the list until a match is found.

```
for lineno1, tup in enumerate(R):
    # iterate over the current tuple
    for i, num in enumerate(tup):
        # compare every number in the tuple to the rest of the list
        for lineno2 in range(lineno1+1, len(R)):
            tup2 = R[lineno2]
            if num == tup2[i]:
                print(f"In line: {lineno1+1} {tup} No. '{num} is found in line {lineno2+1} {tup2}.")
                break
```

Comment: i, yeahit is not efficient, but can refactor the code later if everything works correctly, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got the question right, especially since I think you're almost there.

```
R = [(20, 12, 40, 42, 45), (40, 21, 40, 42, 49),
    (6, 19, 22, 36, 48), (2, 5, 20, 24, 33),
    (8, 12, 24, 28, 44), (3, 15, 29, 30, 37),
    (20, 17, 30, 33, 43), (3, 15, 16, 29, 42),
    (17, 18, 20, 35, 39), (20, 21, 23, 43, 48),
    (14, 24, 30, 40, 45),]
for i,x in enumerate(R):
    a = set(x)
    for j in range(i+1,len(R)):
        y = R[j]
        b = set(y)
        ab = a&b
        for n in ab:
            print(f"In line: {i+1} {x} No. '{n}' is found in line {j+1} {y}.")
```

Comment: yeah, you got it right, but find all the matches in the, i only need first matches. But i can use it if need all the match in the later on in the program, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the problem correctly you just need to iterate a bunch...

```
R = [(20, 12, 40, 42, 45), (40, 21, 40, 42, 49),
    (6, 19, 22, 36, 48), (2, 5, 20, 24, 33),
    (8, 12, 24, 28, 44), (3, 15, 29, 30, 37),
    (20, 17, 30, 33, 43), (3, 15, 16, 29, 42),
    (17, 18, 20, 35, 39), (20, 21, 23, 43, 48),
    (14, 24, 30, 40, 45)...]

for i in range(len(R)):
    list_a = R[i]
    for d in range(len(list_a)):
       val_to_find = list_a[d]
       for j in range((i+1), len(R)):
           list_b = R[j]
           for k in range(list_b):
               cur_val = list_b[k]
               if(val_to_find == cur_val):
                  print("In line: " + string(i) + " " + string(list_a) + " No. " + string(list_a[d]) + " is found in line " + string(k) + " " + string(list_b)")
```

Comment: i get an error when is run this code   for k in range(list_b):
TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer